# I am trying to follow a tutorial here:

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

trying to follow this tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_413231&feature=iv&src_vid=lQW1WQOCri0&v=zVIZSKP3tR8

to use AndEngine and by the time I reach the end I got two errors with the styles.xml files in the "values-v11" and "values-v14" folders (res parrent folder).

resources-->values-v11--> style.xml

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.

in resources-->values-v14--> style.xml

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.

I looked them up and was told to replace them with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources> 
  <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground"> 

    </style> 
</resources>
```

Then I got an error in the main.xml file saying: “No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'” and was told to remove the "android:showAsAction="never" line resulting in this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_settings" 
        android:orderInCategory="100" 
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/> 

</menu>
```

This got rid of the errors. But now when I run it on my phone the phone says "Unfortunately, myTestProject has stopped"

Why is this? here is my logcat errors:

```
05-21 06:52:24.701: W/dalvikvm(8377): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ac19d8)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mystuff/com.mystuff.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mystuff.MainActivity
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mystuff.MainActivity
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
05-21 06:52:24.701: E/AndroidRuntime(8377):      ... 11 more
```

Comment: That's because you're targeting a lower Android version than what's defined in the project. Live all as it was, ang right click to your project-> properties->Android. And try to target a higher Android version

Comment: alright I tried doing just that and changed it to version 4.0 but it still said the same thing when I ran it on my phone...

Comment: So your phone has a lower version of Android?

Comment: Seems very strange. It's not finding the Holo theme, but if you target Android 4 and up you should find it. Have you tried cleeaning your project? Otherwise, you could DELETE values-v11 and values-v14 folders . Try with this